# Are the wheels of a bandsaw exactly the nominal diameter?

Tags: power-tools, band-saw, tool-repair

I recently bought a used bandsaw from a neighbor (AMT 14" model 4113).  It needs new tires, but when I went to measure their width/thickness, I discovered that the wheels are only 13 3/4" in diameter (with the tires on).

Is this the typical size of a 14" bandsaw's wheels?  If I buy 14" tires, will they fit, or do I have to buy 13 3/4" tires?

Comment: This is a comment because I don't know this for a fact. But. Bandsaw tires are rubber, and they are much smaller than the wheels to begin with. You have to stretch them quite a bit to get them on the wheel. It's kind of a pain, actually. I am almost positive 1/4" difference in wheel diameter isn't going to make a difference to the bandsaw tires. It certainly wouldn't trouble me; I wouldn't hesitate to order tires for a 14" wheel to go on a wheel that measures 13 3/4" in diameter.

Comment: One more thought. Fresh bandsaw tires give the wheels a hump in the middle. If the hump is 1/8" (and that sounds about right to me), then 14" could be measuring from hump to hump (13 3/4" for the wheel, 1/8" + 1/8" for the tire hump on either side of the wheel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bandsaw tires are generally sold in 2" increments corresponding to the nominal size of the bandsaw wheels. As the comments indicate, there is some elasticity, so neither the wheels nor tires need to be exact. nominal 14" tires go on nominal 14" wheels.